# How do I make text alignment 508 compliant?

Tags: text-align

Stack overflow once gave a recommendation to align text with the following in css:

`td{text-align:center;}`

Is that 508 compliant? If it is not can you tell me how to properly align text on my website that is 508 compliant?

Answer (score 0):

Using styles to align text or elements is ok to keep the document 508 compliant.  what you have to be concerned with is is the document/page still correctly readable.  As well as do the element tags have the correct 508 markup.

I know this is an old post, but hope this helps for anyone else that runs accros this issue.